# Excel VBA Help - Need to save trackers to master folder

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have 15 trackers set up for my team. They record their daily productivity and at the end of the week I manually go into each tracker and copy the data over to a master tracker.

I know this is inefficient but don't know how to automate this. I assume VBA is the way forward but I have little knowledge. I want to add a button to the staffs trackers, so at the end of the week/day they can submit their work and it will transfer to the master spreadsheet.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Think opposite. Make a `Button` to your master tracker and add `VBA` to copy data from all files in that directory.

Comment: [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405244/copying-a-range-from-all-files-within-a-folder-and-pasting-into-master-workbook)