# VBA Excel - copy a range from all files in a directory and paste into one workbook cumulative on first empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I use a nice code, which is here:

[Copying a range from all files within a folder and pasting into master workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405244/copying-a-range-from-all-files-within-a-folder-and-pasting-into-master-workbook)

I've changed the paste data from columns to rows by providing:

```
 shTarget.Cells(1, lRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

instead of:

```
 shTarget.Cells(1, lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

and to works fine, although everything from the range is copied roughly to the same place. I would like the new data to be copied at the first empty row beneath the data copied earlier (from the first workbook in the directory).

I tried to modify my code by the example here:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-paste-new-data-after-last-row.951096/

https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-vba-copy-paste-values-next-empty-row/

[Copy and Paste a set range in the next empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976329/copy-and-paste-a-set-range-in-the-next-empty-row)

by providing the offset as follows:

```
  shTarget.Cells(1, lRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

but it doesn't work as expected. The data is still copied to the same place several times. Eventually I have just the data from my last workbook in the directory.

My full code looks like this:

```
Sub CopyData(ByRef shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)
Const Bo As String = "A2:H100"
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 shSource.Range(Bo).Copy
 shTarget.Cells(1, lRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
 Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
 End Sub
```

If I change the

```
    lRow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

to

```
    lRow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

then I've got an error:
**Application defined or object defined error**

Is there any way of copying the data on a cumulative basis? I.e. Data from first workbook regardless the range provided (A2:A100) occupies range just A2:A10 and consecutively the data from the 2nd workbook is copied to range A11:A30 and so forth?

Comment: I don't know why you'd use Offset if you're already providing the offset from the lastrow by adding +1 unless you want an empty row in between. Why are you setting the CutCopyMode to xlCopy? How are you calling this Sub?

Comment: You can also paste easily with `shTarget.Range("A" & lRow)` instead of `shTarget.Cells(1, lRow).Offset(1,0)` (which would be pasting in lRow column if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Data Using a Method

**A Quick Fix: Using the End Property (not recommended)**

```vb
Sub CopyDataQF(ByVal shSource As Worksheet, ByVal shTarget As Worksheet)
    Const Bo As String = "A2:H100"
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    FirstRow = shTarget.Cells(shTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    shSource.Range(Bo).Copy
    shTarget.Cells(FirstRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**An Improvement: Using the Find Method**

```vb
Sub CopyData(ByVal shSource As Worksheet, ByVal shTarget As Worksheet)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "A2:H100"
    Const TGT_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the Source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = shSource.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    
    ' Reference the given first Target cell.
    If shTarget.FilterMode Then shTarget.ShowAllData
    Dim tfCell As Range: Set tfCell = shTarget.Range(TGT_FIRST_CELL)
    
    ' Reference the first available Target cell, the cell in the same column
    ' but in the row below the bottom-most non-empty row.
    With tfCell
        Dim tlCell As Range
        Set tlCell = .Resize(shTarget.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
            shTarget.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not tlCell Is Nothing Then
            Set tfCell = shTarget.Cells(tlCell.Row + 1, tfCell.Column)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Copy.
    srg.Copy
    tfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```